# Post-Install of Plone, can't locate folder "zinstance"

Tags: centos, plone, post-install

I have a fresh install of Plone on a CentOS 5.6 server. I used the Unified Insatller and used ZEO ... I can't seem to find my "zinstance" folder. when I do a 'locate zinstance' it gives me the zinstance.sh within the installer it's self, no where else. . Any ideas?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why are you looking for this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed with ZEO there will be no "zinstance" folder. Instead you'll find a "zeoserver" folder, and a "bin" folder with a bunch of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

On linux the unified installer install to /usr/local/plone by default I believe.

Comment: Only for a root install. If you install as a regular user, it'll be in $HOME/Plone